# Adapter and listview shows no content when in root activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am messing around creating a "slide in"(facebook style) menu for Android, this menu will be rendered as a clickable ListView using onItemClickListener. However, when i use a custom adapter for the listview it shows nothing.

The activity which runs it is my "Root activity" which means all other activities extends it. If i place the same code in another activity it can render the listview using this adapter just fine. Also, .setOnItemClickListener seems to do nothing in the root activity. Something does not get setup like it should when this view is created, any ideas? This is the code:

```
public class RootActivity extends Activity {
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

ActionBar actionBar;
ListView slideMenu;

ListMenuAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuOptions;
private String[] menuItems={"Budget","Charts","By category"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rootview);

    menuOptions = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    slideMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slideMenuList);
    slideMenu.setSaveEnabled(false);

    HashMap<String, String> map;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<menuItems.length ; i++ ) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, menuItems[i]);
        map.put(KEY_ID, ""+i);
        menuOptions.add(map);
    }

    adapter = new ListMenuAdapter(this, menuOptions);
    slideMenu.setAdapter(adapter);


    Log.println(9, "slidemendeb2", ""+slideMenu.getAdapter().getCount());
    slideMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.println(9, "Testitemclick", ""+arg0);
        }
    });
}}
```

A sample of another activity which exends RootActivity:

```
public class SpentMain extends RootActivity {
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

ArrayList<Tag> tags;
ArrayList<Integer> tagInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
TagDataSource tagDataSource;
Button costButton;
EditText sum;
Boolean removed = false;

ActionBar actionBar;

CheckBox checkBox;
ListView list;
ListCheckboxAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.rootview);
    costButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.costadd);
    sum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tagsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    tagDataSource = new TagDataSource(this);
    tagDataSource.open();
    tags = tagDataSource.getAllTags();
    tagDataSource.close();
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    for(int i = 0 ; tags.size()>i ; i++ ) {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, tags.get(i).getTitle().toString());
        map.put(KEY_ID, tags.get(i).getId().toString());
        tagsList.add(map);
    }

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    adapter = new ListCheckboxAdapter(this, tagsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Row click event
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            for(int i = 0; tagInts.size()>i; i++) {
                if(tagInts.get(i)==position) {
                    tagInts.remove(i);
                    removed = true;
                }
            } 

            if(removed==false) {
                tagInts.add(position+1);
            }
            removed = false;

            for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(i);
                if(nextChild.getClass()==android.widget.CheckBox.class) {
                    checkBox = (CheckBox) nextChild;
                    if(checkBox.isChecked()==true) {
                        checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    } else {
                        checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });}
```

As i said, if i use this adapter to render it within SpentMain it works fine but not within RootActivity. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i managed to fix the problem, what i did was to move the code out of onCreate in RootActivity and into its on method "buildSideMenu()". I then call that method in my SpentMain.class onCreate method like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rootview);
    super.buildSideMenu();                                                     
}
```

I noticed that if i call super.buildSideMenu() before setContentView(R.layout.rootview) it will not work. So the problem was that since super.onCreate was being run before setContentView some things had probably not been set up properly at the time my menu was being built. Hope this can help someone else!